# identify dynamically changing radio button and text box to fill selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a table to fill in which radio button id and text box id keeps changing. See below Image

[image]

Now if you see the image I need to fill radio button for say some database db1.
every time the db name will change say sometime db1, sometime db2 and so on. The list is not in ascending order. The database names are different in real case.

I need to click radio button for db and password field as well.

I see the HTML tag is as follows-

For radiobutton:

```
<input id="emT:pb1pc1:t1:0:t1c41it2::content" name="emT:pb1pc1:t1:0:t1c41it2" class="x25" type="password" autocomplete="off">
```

For password:

```
<input id="emT:pb1pc1:t1:0:t1sb1::content" name="emT:pb1pc1:t1:0:t1sb1" class="xqf" type="checkbox" value="t" onclick="this.focus()" _afrfoc="y1497498975541">
```

The id field keeps changing like -

```
emT:pb1pc1:t1:0:t1c41it2::content
emT:pb1pc1:t2:0:t1c41it2::content
emT:pb1pc1:t3:0:t1c41it2::content
emT:pb1pc1:t4:0:t1c41it2::content
```

How to click radiobutton based on db name? As I don't see any db name here in HTML code.

Comment: can you give us the complete DOM for the entire table please?

Comment: @Rahul bhai HTML code please.

Comment: Try `//*[normalize-space()="db1"]/preceding::input`

Comment: can you add the db1 column html dom?